# How to get single row from mysql databse table using inner join query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following 2 tables in mysql database :

1) products

```
p_id      p_title   p_price   u_id  
----------------------------------
1         tile      123       25
2         tile      133       24
3         tile      143       25
```

2) product_images

```
id       img_name   p_id      u_id   
1        name       1         25
2        name       1         25
3        name       2         24
```

I want to get all row from `products` table and only one row from `product_images` table. So to get this I am using following sql query but it's return all rows from `product_images` table. Should be one !

**My Query :**

```
$get_menu = mysqli_query($conn, 
"SELECT DISTINCT products.p_title, products.p_price, 
product_images.p_list_image, chef_profile.live_at, chef_profile.fname,
chef_profile.lname FROM products LEFT JOIN product_images ON products.p_id
= product_images.p_id LEFT JOIN chef_profile ON products.u_id = 
chef_profile.u_id GROUP BY product_images.p_list_image") or die('sorry');
```

I am using this query in php `while loop` so that I want to show all unique data from `products` table and only one image from `product_images` table.

```
$num_menu =  mysqli_num_rows($get_menu);
    while( $get_result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_menu) ) {
        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($get_result);*/
        $menu_title = htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_title']);
        $menu_price = htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_price']);        
        $menu_image = htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_list_image']) ? htmlspecialchars($get_result['p_list_image']) : "no-menu-preview.png";
        $live_at =  htmlspecialchars($get_result['live_at']);
        $fname = htmlspecialchars($get_result['fname']);
        $lname = htmlspecialchars($get_result['lname']);

        // echo..........data.. her...
    }
```

Comment: Can you show one sample output ?

Comment: Do you understand, that you use 3 tables but for us you explained 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have it.

You only have to group by p_id to get 1 result for each product.

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.p_title, products.p_price, product_images.p_list_image, chef_profile.live_at, chef_profile.fname, chef_profile.lname
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_images ON products.p_id = product_images.p_id
LEFT JOIN chef_profile ON products.u_id = chef_profile.u_id
GROUP BY products.p_id
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Exactty what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT products.p_title, 
products.p_price, 
product_images.p_list_image, 
chef_profile.live_at, 
chef_profile.fname,
chef_profile.lname 

FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_images ON products.p_id = product_images.p_id 
LEFT JOIN chef_profile ON products.u_id = chef_profile.u_id 

GROUP BY products.p_id,product_images.p_list_image
```